# Getting Error when attempting to save to database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm a beginner with android studio, so I'm stumbling my way through building my first app.  I've come up with and error when attempting to save my data to a database.  Whenever I try to save any digits, the app crashes.

Database Java file:

```
package com.miahollins.basketballfinal;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by pumpkin on 6/17/16.
 */
public class DataHandler {
public static final String GAMES = "games_played";
public static final String GAMES2 = "games_started";
public static final String GAMES3 = "points";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "statstable";
public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "mydatabase.sqlite";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table statstable (games_played VARCHAR not null, games_started VARCHAR not null, points VARCHAR not null)";

DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
Context ctx;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public DataHandler(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);

}


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx){
        super(ctx, DATA_BASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        } catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS statstable");
        onCreate(db);

    }
}

public DataHandler open(){
    db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    dbhelper.close();
}

public long insertData(String games_played, String games_started, String points){
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(GAMES, games_played);
    content.put(GAMES2, games_started);
    content.put(GAMES3, points);
    return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);


}

public Cursor returnData(){
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{GAMES, GAMES2, GAMES3},null, null, null, null, null);

}


}
```

In my logcat I get an error saying that columns cannot be found.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the logcat error?

Comment: Not sure if its the problem, but it should be "CREATE TABLE" in caps. Which i think would stop your db from being created

Comment: also, if thus is your first db, there is no reason to use db version "2" but if it is done, don't try to fix it.

Comment: @Buildersrejected SQL keywords are not case sensitive. A too-high DB version does not hurt, and increasing it probably was necessary after a change.

Comment: @Buildersrejected Thank you! After I changed it to "CREATE_TABLE" it worked!